# reCAPTCHA first attempt causes it to reset. Firebase phoneAuthVerifier

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

Hello I'm having issues implementing recaptcha into our firebase project. I'm using it with firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider, to initially enroll a second factor and then use the recaptcha for multi-factor authentication on login.

I've used the https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa doc for the implementation and it does work but it resets on the first successful attempt. The tickbox gets checked but instantly the whole recaptcha rerenders/is reset.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAy3H.jpg (here is a tiny video of that reset behaviour)

The fact that it is rerendering makes me think it is an error in the implementation and possibly to do with React but I am struggling to solve it.

**Login Function**

```
const frontendLogin = () => {

const { email, password } = registerDetails
firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(data => {
    // if (data.user.emailVerified) {
    axios.get(`/users/${data.user.uid}`)
      .then(res => {
        // Handle login for users not enrolled with multi-factor
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    if (error.code === 'auth/multi-factor-auth-required') {
      setResolver(error.resolver)
      setHints(error.resolver.hints[0])
      setPhoneVerifyRequired(true)
      // Ask user which second factor to use.
      if (error.resolver.hints[selectedIndex].factorId ===
        firebase.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.FACTOR_ID) {
        const phoneInfoOptions = {
          multiFactorHint: error.resolver.hints[selectedIndex],
          session: error.resolver.session
        };
        const phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider(appAuth);
        const recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
          captchaRef.current,
          {
            'size': 'normal',
            'callback': function (response) {
              console.log('captcha!')
              handleSolved()

            },
            'expired-callback': function () {
              console.log('captcha expired')
            },
            'hl': locale
          },
          firebaseApp);

        // Send SMS verification code
        return phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, recaptchaVerifier)
          .then(function (verificationId) {
            setVerificationId(verificationId)
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      } else {
        // Unsupported second factor.
      }
    } else {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}

const handleSolved = () => {
  setCaptchad(true)
  setIsLoading(false)
}

const handleRecaptcha = () => {
var cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
  verificationId, verificationCode);
console.log(cred)
var multiFactorAssertion =
  firebase.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(cred);
// Complete sign-in.

resolver.resolveSignIn(multiFactorAssertion)
  .then(function (data) {
    // User successfully signed in with the second factor phone number.
    // Handle login for users enrolled with multi-factor
  })
}
```

I am unsure as to why this approach isn't working but I believe it may be to do with React? I have looked into using a React Recaptcha package but as the docs were just written in javascript I've just tried to implement it in this way.

I haven't deviated too far from the docs only to set state with elements including the verification ID that is returned from the successful recaptcha etc.

I also appreciate I am setting state too much and need to refactor the state at the top of the component but as I'm still fleshing this component out it hasn't been refactored yet so I apologise it's a bit messy!

If anyone has any pointers that would be great or if I need to provide more code then let me know, any help is appreciated!